# Resin curing and adhesion materials

Tags: bond

I have a question that applies to material science and chemistry, I have no idea how to answer it (my chem is weak) so I thought I would ask it...

I'm trying to make an SLA/DLP type 3D printer that uses DLP light to cure resins in UV spectrum...

I'm good to go mechanically and electronically... But I'm at the point now where I need to decide what build plate material to use... I need to resin to adhere well to the build plate for the printer to work properly... I've been doing research, but havent found much... Most people use aluminum or other metal plates, but I know there is a better material out there, I just haven't found it yet...

I found the MSDS stats on a certain resin, and thought if I figure out what the resin is made of, I can figure out what materials it will want to stick to given it's chemical properties... So here it is

Isobornyl acrylate (15-30%)

Acrylic monomer (15-30%)

Urethane acrylate (10-30%)

Acrylic monomer (5-10%)

Epoxy acrylate (5-10%)

Acrylate oligomer (2-5%)

Photoinitiator (<1%)

http://www.sculpteo.com/media/imagecontent/DOC-06119-Objet-VeroClear-RGD810-US.pdf

Do you have any ideas of what this would naturally want to stick to?